# Set backgroundcolor of a Polar Plot using Colormaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, colormap

I created a polar plot with matplotlib. Additionally, I have a value that lays between 0 and 3. The value should determine the background color I set the color of the plot now like:

```py
    if 0.8 < x and x < 1.2:
            color = 'white'
    elif 1.2 < x and x < 1.4:
            color = 'white'
```

etc...
and later:

```
ax.set_facecolor(color)
```

However, that's not very convenient.
My goal is that the color is white when its value is `1`. For a value below `1`, blue and for above `1`, red. But continuously changing. Something like this gradient:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `'bwr_r'` [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) (it is the reversed version of `'bwr'`). A colormap gets a parameter between 0 and 1. 0 is mapped to the lowest color (red for `'bwr_r'`), 0.5 is mapped to the middle color (white) and 1 to the highest color.

If your value of 0 needs to map to red and 1 to white, dividing the value by 2 puts it in the correct range.  For values between 1 and 3, one could subtract 1, divide by 4 and add 0.5 to the result to map these values to the colors from white to blue. So, the code could look like `ax.set_facecolor(plt.cm.bwr_r(val / 2 if val <= 1 else 0.5 + (val - 1) / 4))`.

Alternatively, a [`TwoSlopeNorm`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm.html) does these calculations in a friendlier way via `TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=1, vmin=0, vmax=3)`. If you would like the reds and the blues less saturated, change it to `TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=1, vmin=-1, vmax=5)`.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm

norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=1, vmin=0, vmax=3)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=6, nrows=2, figsize=(12, 5),
                         subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'}, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.2, 'wspace': 0.25})
for i, ax in enumerate(np.ravel(axes)):
    val = i / 4
    ax.set_title(f'val = {val}')
    ax.set_facecolor(plt.cm.bwr_r(norm(val)))
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]